# Using partially implemented interfaces

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, inheritance, implementations

Consider the following hierarchy in C++ notation:

```
class A
    {
    public:
        virtual void doStuff()=0;
        virtual void doOtherStuff()=0;
    };

class B:public A
    {
    public:
        void doStuff();
        void doOtherStuff();
    };

class C:public A
    {
    public:
        void doStuff();
        void doOtherStuff();
    };
```

Now, assume that the code for doStuff is identical in B and C. What is the best practice of

- implementing doStuff in a class D:public A and let B and C derive from A
- Let the real task be performed in a function that is called from doStuff in both B and C

Somehow the latter seems more clean, is it? It should be noted that there are other methods in B and C with common implementations as well, and that in the underlaying model, the concept of D does not exist.

Comment: Option one seems a lot cleaner. You would call an external method from all the methods that should actually implement it? That sounds like a lot of code duplication and unnecessary complexity. A common base class is a good way to group shared functionality.

Comment: @JeroenVannel But does it make sense to say that B objects is substitutable for D objects? The latter avoids the more or less artificial construct D (no such thing exists in the underlaying model).

Comment: You would create a separate class as well except you would just basically create a helper class and call its functions, right? A class shouldn't rely on another class to do the things it can do perfectly fine itself. And yes, it does make sense to say that B is substitutable with D: after all, B contains all functionality that's held in D.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what varies, so it's hard to suggest what the best encapsulation is. For example, are you suggesting a class D because there are other implementors of A that wouldn't want the common `doStuff()` implementation?

Comment: @neontapir Exactly: There might be other implementations of A that do not share the implementation of doStuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class E to hold the shared implementation of doStuff

```
class E : class A
{
override doStuff() {}
}
```

and have classes B and C inherit from E. This allows you to maintain the inheritance if B and C still need to be types derived from A, but allows A and other derivations to not share the same implementation and B and C